# Directly Connected Multihomed Hosts

Tags: design

I'm looking to directly connect a host (dual NICs) to a clustered appliance. The clustered appliance consists of two controllers each with their own NIC and VIP. In the event of a controller failure, or planned outage, a VIP will be migrated to the remaining controller. The appliance runs a couple applications, each pinned to it's own VIP.

If I assign everything to the same subnet I can use static routes on the host to insure the host's NIC1 talks to the VIP1 it's connected with, but if that controller fails the VIP will move to the other controller and that application would then be only accessible through the host's NIC2.

The obvious solution is to introduce a switch but we were trying to avoid the added hardware. One thought was to write a small service on the host to continuously ping the VIPs and change the static routing if the pings ever fail. Any other suggestions?

```
------------------------------
|                            |
|          Host              |
|                            | 
| NIC1                  NIC2 |
------------------------------
   |                     |
   |                     |
   |                     | 
------------------------------
| C1 (VIP1)        C2 (VIP2) |     
|                            |  
|      Dual Controller       |
|    Clustered Appliance     |
|                            |    
------------------------------
```

Thanks,

Comment: Most network engineers have a very different definition of *multihoming*.

Comment: most devices will not let you configure two interfaces on the same subnet without some sort of layer 2 bonding.